# Как отключить буферизцию при записи в файл в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, файлы, буферизация

Как сделать, чтобы данные сразу сбрасывались на диск при записи новой строки?

```
var
  f: textfile;
  i: integer;
begin
  AssignFile(f, 'file.txt');
  ReWrite(f);
  for i := 0 to 200 do
  begin
    WriteLn(f, 'string number ' + IntToStr(i));
    Sleep(1000);
  end;
  CloseFile(f);
end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо добавить

```
Flush(f);
```

после `WriteLn`